# MySQL - join two tables, group and count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
reviewStatusPhases - id|name
```

and

```
userPhase - id|reviewStatusPhase_id|user_id|created_at|updated_at
```

The **reviewStatusPhases** table have records inserted (Active, Inactive, On Pause, Terminated...), and **userPhase** is empty.

The tables are connected via

```
 userPhase.reviewStatusPhase_id = reviewStatusPhases.id
```

one to one.

Is it possible that in one query I get all reviewStatusPhases, and cound how many users are in each phase? In this case I will get something like this:

```
Active (0 Users)
Inactive (0 Users)
On Pause (0 Users)
Terminated (0 Users)
```

Comment: Sure - LEFT JOIN reviewStatusPhases with userPhase (so that you still get records for those phases that no user entries exist for yet), GROUP BY the phase id, and COUNT ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm making some assumptions here (e.g. INNER JOIN versus LEFT JOIN in the join, and DISTINCT in the count), but it sounds like you just want

```
SELECT reviewStatusPhases.name, COUNT(DISTINCT userPhase.user_id)
FROM userPhase INNER JOIN reviewStatusPhases
   ON userPhase.reviewStatusPhase_id = reviewStatusPhases.id
GROUP BY reviewStatusPhases.name
```

Answer (score 2):

Query will be as follows:

```
SELECT r.name as `name`, count(u.id) as `count` FROM reviewStatusPhases r LEFT OUTER JOIN userPhase u ON r.id = u.reviewStatusPhase_id GROUP BY r.name
```

1. left outer join with reviewStatusPhases on left to show all names.
2. group by names of reviewStatusPhases.
3. display reviewStatusPhases name and count of user id's (to neglect null values)

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN` as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(m.UserId) FROM Table1 m 
LEFT JOIN Table2 k ON k.StatusId = m.StatusId
WHERE k.Status = 'Inactive'
```

You can easily use the **Status** column to track the users and their activities. In your case, **ReviewStatus**.

Comment: For the multiple status at a time, you may use `k.Status IN ('active', 'inactive')`. Though the second answer would be more appropriate using `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

I hope the following will be helpful

```
SELECT RPS.Name,  COUNT(UP.user_id) 
FROM reviewStatusPhases RPS
LEFT OUTER JOIN userphases UP ON RPS.id = UP.reviewStatusPhase_id
GROUP BY RPS.Name
ORDER BY RPS.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT s.s_level AS 'Level', 
COUNT(DISTINCT s.s_id) AS Schools, 
COUNT(DISTINCT st.st_id) AS Teachers 
FROM schools AS s
JOIN school_teachers AS st ON st.st_school_idFk = s.s_id AND st.st_status = 1
WHERE s.s_status = 1 
GROUP BY s.s_level
```